# Sublime not allowing ending curly bracket

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3

I can no longer type an ending curly bracket in Sublime Text 3 - nothing happens when typing one. I can type it in every other application I've tried (e.g. Notepad)

```
} - not working
) - working
] - working
```

Anybody else experiencing this? Is it some kind plugin that's stopping me from writing a `}`?

---

I've found a workaround, but don't know if it has any side-effects:

```
  // Adding a sortcut in Key Bindings - User to get my } back
  // (note: swedish keyboard)
  {
      "keys": ["alt+shift+9"],
      "command": "insert",
      "args": { "characters": "}" }
  },
```

Comment: Have you changed your key-bindings?

Comment: Have you tried typing it in notepad?

Comment: Maybe this is a sign that you should switch to non-curly bracket language like Python or Ruby :)